# How to repeat an action in python to make my code simpler

Tags: python

Im trying to make my code repeat the action of picking a random symbol in a string multiple times. The code below essentially repeats a letter picked 6 times like this "DDDDDD" instead of the desired result of "DYBDdsf" for example. Im trying to create a password gen for my first project. The user input is an arbitrary number for now as I'm still in the process of learning Tkinter.

```
import string

string.ascii_letters='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
string.number_symbols='!@#$%^&*()'

userInput = 6

print((random.choice(string.ascii_letters))* userInput)
```

Comment: That's what `loops` are for.

Answer (score 2):

First, don't redefine `string.ascii_letters`. Just use is as is. Then you can use [`random.choices()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) instead of choice() to pick a number, `k` of random choices. With that you can `join` them into a string:

```
import string
import random 

userInput = 6
pw = "".join(random.choices(string.ascii_letters, k=userInput))
print(pw)
# sRVhZl
```

If you want to append the ascii letters you can add other symbols like:

```
userInput = 6
alphabet = string.ascii_letters + '!@#$%^&*()'

print("".join(random.choices(alphabet, k=userInput)))
# qkfpH$
```

Comment: a different comment told me to input ``random.choices(string.ascii_letters, k=6)`` can you please explain what the ``("".join`` part means?

Comment: @r_33 `choices()` returns a list like `['a', 'l','K', 'w', 'X', 'p']` but you want a single strangle string. `"".join()` takes a list and joins the elements with `""` — an empty string —  resulting in `alKwXp`.

Comment: does the k hold any significant value?

Comment: @r_33 `k` determines how many choices, in other words how long the string is. In this case, 6. See the linked documentation.

Comment: oops sorry just getting used to using the platform. I managed to get the result i was wanting thanks to your help. Much appreciated ;)

Comment: any suggestions for getting the user to input a number instead of having one set?

Comment: Sure, use `input()` -->  `userInput = int(input("How long"))`

Comment: ``from tkinter import *

import random
import string

string.ascii_letters='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
string.number_symbols='!@#$%^&*()'

userLetterInput = input("How many letters would you like in your password?: ")
userSymbolInput = input("How many symbols would you like in your password?: ")

letterResult = "".join(random.choices(string.ascii_letters, k=userLetterInput))

symbolResult = "".join(random.choices(string.number_symbols, k=userSymbolInput))

print("".join(letterResult + symbolResult))``
but got a  error :(

Comment: Notice that I converted the string returned from `input()` to an integer.

Comment: nvm fixed it ``import random
import string

string.ascii_letters='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
string.number_symbols='!@#$%^&*()'

userLetterInput = int(input("How many letters would you like in your password?: "))
userSymbolInput = int(input("How many symbols would you like in your password?: "))

letterResult = ''.join([random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for i in range(userLetterInput)])

symbolResult = ''.join([random.choice(string.number_symbols) for i in range(userSymbolInput)])

print("".join(letterResult + symbolResult))``

Answer (score 1):

You can actually use a function from the random library pretty close to what you have.

```
print((random.choices(string.ascii_letters, k=userInput)))
```

This will essentially pick from the `string.ascii_letters` and choose `userInput` amount of characters to append the print screen. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can select several ítems of a list with random.choices(). the k value indicates the number of selected items. In your print you need to write

```
random.choices(string.ascii_letters, k=6)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the same letter 6 times because you are multiplying the result of choosing a random letter by 6. Instead, you can use a loop:

```
import string
import random

string.ascii_letters='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
string.number_symbols='!@#$%^&*()'

userInput = 6

for i in range(0, userInput):
    print(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension:

```
import string
import random

print(''.join([random.choice(string.ascii_letters + '!@#$%^&*()') for i in range(6)]))
```

Output:

```
kh)qlE
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import string

string.ascii_letters='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
string.number_symbols='!@#$%^&*()'

userLetterInput = 6
userSymbolInput = 2

letterResult = "".join(random.choices(string.ascii_letters, k=userLetterInput))

symbolResult = "".join(random.choices(string.number_symbols, k=userSymbolInput))

print("".join(letterResult + symbolResult))

UraeXS)@
```